# ListView positionViewAtIndex() not working

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have two `ListView`s in a QML project that are both running off of the same model. I am trying to get them to start out at different indices (the model starts with 2 `ListElement`s in it). In order to do this, I call `positionViewAtIndex` when the component completes:

```
ListView {
    model: mymodel
    Component.onCompleted: positionViewAtIndex(1,ListView.Beginning)
    //...
}
```

However, neither `ListView` actually is positioned at the desired index. Is there something I'm not doing? The only solution that I have seen for this problem is to ensure that you're not calling the method before the `ListView` completes, but I am doing that.

I am using Qt 5.2/QtQuick 2.0.

**Edit:** After playing around with the other positioner functions, I have found that none of them work. I have also found that changing `currentIndex` does not work either. Furthermore, I have found that `currentIndex` is not being changed with the view -- `onCurrentIndexChanged` is never being fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured it out. It turns out that a `ListView` instantiates its delegates before it worries about its own properties...so the delegate was only reading off of the `ListView`'s width before the `ListView` set its own dimensions. When a delegate has a width/height property in the orientation of the view equal to zero, the view will not know where to scroll to when `positionViewAtIndex()` is called. So, in order to fix this, you have to use a conditional binding:

```
Component {
    id: myDelegate
    Item {
        width: ListView.view.width == 0 ? 480 /*or some preset*/ : ListView.view.width
    }
}
```

This will give the delegate a nonzero width and cause the `positionViewAtIndex()` function to work.

Of course, if your `ListView` is vertical, then you need to set the `height` property and not the `width` property.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can set currentIndex to 1

Comment: As I noted in my question (after I edited it), changing `currentIndex` did absolutely nothing. Furthermore, manually changing the position of the view does not fire the `onCurrentIndexChanged` signal...

Comment: After quick testing with qtquick 1.1 it only works if I set ListView height less than needed to viewport. CurrentIndexChanged signal will work if you turn on the highlighting

Comment: Neither of those worked for me...I should point out - I am using QtQuick 2.0 (Qt 5.2), but I don't think that that would be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ive tested it both with QtQuick2 and QtQuick1 `Component.onCompleted: positionViewAtIndex(1,ListView.Beginning)` do works for me.
Note that [If positioning the view at index would cause empty space to be displayed at the beginning or end of the view, the view will be positioned at the boundary](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#positionViewAtIndex-method).

Comment: I'm not positioning the view such that there would be empty space showing. Could you perhaps show the code that works for you?

Comment: Okay...I tried your example as-is and it works...so it's probably something that I've done somewhere. I'll play around with it and report back on what the problem is.

Comment: So, I discovered that if I hard-coded the delegate's width (my `ListView` is horizontal), then it would work, so I imagine that the delegate is being created with dimensions that the `ListView` isn't recognizing. However, I need to be able to dynamically set the width of the delegate (to support different devices). I'll keep looking.